# How can I build a dict from input of [key,value] pairs separated by a space using just one Python3 statement

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to build a dictionary from input of `[key,value]` pairs separated by a space using just one `Python3` statement.

I want to create a dictionary consisting of "n" words, entering a "key" and "value" separated by a space, using input (), something like this:

```
d={}
n = 3
d = [ map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: key value key value or [key,value] [key,value] ?

Comment: Please provide sample input in your question

Comment: I want to create a dictionary consisting of "n" words, entering a "key" and "value" separated by a space, using input ()

Comment: d={}
n = 3
d = [ map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)]
print d

Comment: Something like this only in Python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one-liner, interleaving the result of split with itself, with a step so keys & values are presented in as a tuple directly taken by `dict`:

```
s = "key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3"  # input()

d = dict(zip(s.split()[::2],s.split()[1::2]))

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

note that the one liner forces to perform the `split` operation twice. So it's better to assign the result of `split` first in a variable.